# How do I replace DropwizardAppRule in Junit5

Tags: java, dropwizard, junit5, junit-rule

In Junit 4 I could do something like

```
@ClassRule
public DropwizardAppRule<Configuration> app = new DropwizardAppRule<>(MyApp.class);

...

app.getLocalPort()
```

How do I replicate this behavior in Junit 5? From [this](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/2166) github issue it seems like I need to use `@ExtendWith(DropwizardExtensionsSupport.class)`, but its unclear how

Comment: What is jiminy...?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Jimmy is what you get when your phone autocorrects junit 5 :)

Comment: Lol that makes more sense ... :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dropwizard 1.3.0 [added](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/2166) JUnit5 support by introducing the [**`DropwizardExtensionsSupport`** class](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/dropwizard-testing/apidocs/io/dropwizard/testing/junit5/DropwizardExtensionsSupport.html).

Specifically, if you need to start / stop the application at the beginning / end of your tests (which is what `DropwizardAppRule` does), there's a [**`DropwizardAppExtension`**](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/dropwizard-testing/apidocs/io/dropwizard/testing/junit5/DropwizardAppExtension.html) available.

**Your example, rewritten for JUnit5:**

```
@ExtendWith(DropwizardExtensionsSupport.class)
public class MyTest {

    public static final DropwizardAppExtension<Config> app = new DropwizardAppExtension<>(MyApp.class);

    ...

       // app.getLocalPort() is also available

}
```

Unfortunately, the JUnit5 support [doesn't seem to be documented yet](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.5/docs/manual/testing.html).

**Links:**

- [DropwizardExtensionsSupport](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/dropwizard-testing/apidocs/io/dropwizard/testing/junit5/DropwizardExtensionsSupport.html)
- [DropwizardAppExtension](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/dropwizard-testing/apidocs/io/dropwizard/testing/junit5/DropwizardAppExtension.html)
- [DropwizardAppExtension#getLocalPort](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/dropwizard-testing/apidocs/io/dropwizard/testing/junit5/DropwizardAppExtension.html#getLocalPort--)

Comment: broken lins to DW-JavaDocs